# Ops Hub User Matching

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Can you please tell me where OPSHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility pulls the user data from when doing a match, both on-prem and online?  I am trying to match users for just one project, which has 41 users, however the utility wants me to match 119 users, many of which are not even associated with any project on my on-Prem TFS server.  Additionally, where is the online user information pulled from?  I have some that are displayed as email address, others seem to be usernames.  Obviously I need to straighten this out so I can map to the correct users.  Also, some users exist on Prem that will never map to any online user, so how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

*Project Collection Valid Users* are pulled from both the end points. This is done to make the user mapping explicit. In some cases, a user might have done some changes in a project but is now no longer a part of the project. If such user is not mapped then, loss of information is observed when such data is migrated.

For users of on-prem who are not going to be in VSTS. You can map them as default to any other user. (Or maybe create a dedicated user for) Basically, all changes done by those users in your on-prem TFS would be shown as done by the user with which they would be mapped.